# nvalid value: 30004: provided port is already allocated

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am trying to create a Service: NodePort for one of the pods I have deployed,

**Below is my service definition**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: voting-service
  labels:
    name: voting-service
    app: demo-voting-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30004
  selector:
    name: voting-app-pod
    app: demo-voting-app
```

I am deploying this service with command below

```sh
kubectl create -f voting-app-service.yaml
```

**Here is the Error**

```
The Service "voting-service" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Invalid value: 30004: provided port is already allocated
```

So I tried to find services that are using port 30004 with netstat and lsof commands but couldnt find any services using that port.

```sh
➜  Voting-app kubectl create -f voting-app-service.yaml
The Service "voting-service" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Invalid value: 30004: provided port is already allocated
➜  Voting-app sudo netstat -lntp | grep 30004     
➜  Voting-app lsof -i :30004                      
➜  Voting-app
```

minikube version: v1.22.0
kubectl : 1.21 version

Comment: you can change the port in the service file and apply it.

Comment: @HarshManvar yes I agree with you, how can I find why this error is coming even though the port was free ?

Comment: Found it, one of my other pod using that port, got it with kubectl get svc command.

Answer (score 6):

As @HarshManvar mentioned you can change the port in the service file for one that isn't allocated.

Later you find that port `30004` was already allocated as there was a pod using that port:

> kubectl get svc | grep 30004

Answer (score 1):

seem be an issue
NodePort creation with statically assigned portNumber collide in multi-master HA cluster
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/89937

could fix by command:

```
kubectl create svc nodeport test --tcp=5678:8080
kubectl delete svc test
```

Comment: This helped after upgrading to Tanzu Kubernetes 1.23. But why??

Comment: Nvm it seems to be time based or random, rather than being related to the creation of another nodeport service.